# Command to return value in Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

How can I return a value in a Windows batch file? I can do it in Unix using `exit 1` but how can I do it in Windows?

Comment: Do you mean Windows **BATCH** file?  Or do you actually have [GNU Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) installed on Windows?

Comment: Windows BATCH file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a windows batch file to return a value back to the command shell use

```
exit /b yourexitcode
```

e.g

```
exit /b 3
```

will retun 3 in `%ERRORLEVEL%`

Answer (score 3):

In Windows:

```
exit /b 1
```